# How to solve this permission for button click problem?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Actually I have a asp.net mvc web application Now I have a button which if a user has sufficient rights then its visibility is set as true or false (using jquery)
Now, recently working through firebug in the browser i changed its visibility to true.
It performed the action(which is wrong).

How to prevent this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform the authorization on the controller method or parent class that clicking your button invokes.

You can use the AuthorizeAttribute class to decorate your class.

There's more [information here on MSDN regarding the Authorize Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx).

You'll see examples on that page such as:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Super User")]
     public ActionResult AdministratorsOnly()
     {
         return View();
     }
```

Comment: ok.. thats correct for roles... But if i have to show/hide to enable/disable a button's functionality using a status(eg. A user in status condition 4 has rights to see a button Download). But in Present case if i am through firebug changing its visibility so its still working(which should not happen).. Thanks for ur time.. :)

Answer (score 0):

The underlining issue is validation should not be done client side. The clients browser can activate / deactivate anything and change any value.

If the user doe not have sufficient permissions do not render the button at all or (if design requires it) render a disabled button with no link so that the user could activate via dom manipulation but not click.

```
<% if (((int) ViewData["permission"]) >= 3) { // one of many ways to do this, perhaps not the best but quick. %>
   <input type="button" />
<% } %>
```